# How to populate array of objects in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, postman, mongoose-populate

I have this code -

```
const getAllCourses = async (req, res) => {
    const courses = await Course.find({});

    try {
        await courses.populate('professor')
        
        res.send({ status: 200, data: { courses } });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ status: 500, message: "Internal server error." });
    }

};
```

Also, this is the response I'm getting from postman -

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "courses": [
            {
                "_id": "61dc47f58f88c1a7e9bd36b6",
                "name": "Course1",
                "professor": "61dc1299431cd669faad7d0f",
                "students": [
                    {
                        "student": "61dc0b7f103b531f105e8e4c",
                        "_id": "61dc47f58f88c1a7e9bd36b7"
                    },
                    {
                        "student": "61dc220885886a9f1d8e94d0",
                        "_id": "61dc47f58f88c1a7e9bd36b8"
                    }
                ],
                "createdAt": "2022-01-10T14:51:33.313Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-01-10T14:51:33.313Z",
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "61dc47fb8f88c1a7e9bd36bf",
                "name": "Course2",
                "professor": "61dc1299431cd669faad7d0f",
                "students": [
                    {
                        "student": "61dc0b7f103b531f105e8e4c",
                        "_id": "61dc47fb8f88c1a7e9bd36c0"
                    },
                    {
                        "student": "61dc220885886a9f1d8e94d0",
                        "_id": "61dc47fb8f88c1a7e9bd36c1"
                    }
                ],
                "createdAt": "2022-01-10T14:51:39.704Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-01-10T14:51:39.704Z",
                "__v": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to populate the professor and the students but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried populating "courses.professor", "course.professor", "professor" but nothing worked for me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it by chaining the `populate` method directly after the `Course.find({})`.

Solution:

```
const getAllCourses = async (req, res) => {
    const courses = await Course.find({}).populate('professor').populate('students.student');

    try {
        res.send({ status: 200, data: { courses } });        
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ status: 500, message: err.message });
    }
};
```

From the docs for [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

> We may populate a single document, multiple documents, a plain object, multiple plain objects, or **all objects returned from a query**.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate) is an example of how this can be done for a document with an array `friends` on it:

```
User.
  findOne({ name: 'Val' }).
  populate({
    path: 'friends',
    // Get friends of friends - populate the 'friends' array for every friend
    populate: { path: 'friends' }
  });
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. The error I get is "courses.populate is not a function". And if I try to iterate over each course with the `forEach` method it doesn't work either. The only thing that works is if I type `courses[0].populate('professor')`, but for some reason I can't loop through all of the courses.

Comment: Courses is an array, which wouldn't have a `populate` function on it. `courses[0]` is a mongodb cursor, which will have the `populate` function.

Ideally, you would do `populate` as part of an aggregation stage though so that instead of looping through and populating each one as part of a seperate query, you let mongo do that.